# Send JSON object to Java Back-end with JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, ajax, rest, jax-rs

I'm trying to send an JSON object to my Java EE server using Ajax and JAX RS.

When i do the client request i get the **HTTP415** error.

Here's the code..

```
var obj = {nome:"a", cognome:"b"};
$.post("http://localhost:8080/MyApp/resources/Class/Method",obj).done(function(data) {
    alert( "..." + data);
})
.fail(function() {
     alert( "error" );
});
```

Java Class:

```
public class Oggetto implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String nome;
private String cognome;

public Oggetto() {}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}
public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
} }
```

And the Rest Class:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/Method")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String Mex(final Oggetto obj) {

        return "ok";

    }
```

I get an error from the Browser console. **HTTP415: UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE**

I tried with an AngularJS call, but it's the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the content type. Also you need to `stringify` the request object. See this example with `$.ajax` (`$post` is a shorthand)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/resources/Class/Method",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj), 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"      
    }
}).done(function(data){
```

Answer (score 0):

As your Rest class method annotated with **@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)** 
so it only expects Content-Type of the request to be application/json.

Either remove @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) or send Content-Type with request as shown above by [pedrofb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371459/pedrofb).